# how to make tornado auto restart when certain files changes

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tornado

I'm using Tornado working with Python 3 and Linux server, when I edit and save some text or XML files I want Tornado to restart itself. I checked the document and found the autoreload module and the watch function [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/autoreload.html#watch).

It seems it only worked for pyo files. What can I do if I want it to reload when a certain URI is modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the file added must be an absolute path.

```
def addwatchfiles(*paths):
    for p in paths:
        autoreload.watch(os.path.abspath(p))
addwatchfiles('config.xml')
```

config.xml is at the same directory in where the server's python file start at.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the debug flag to True in settings forces Tornado to reload whenever a file is modified or whenever a URI is changed in app.py (or where ever you have defined your handlers). Tornado also automatically reloads template files so any changes in there will be seen instantly.

```
    settings = {
                'debug':True,
               # other stuff
    }
    tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

Comment: i've already set the debug flag to true.it didn't work.if i read some xml files before the application started.Modify the xml files wouldn't trig the application to restart. is there any way i can set it?

Comment: if the autoreload watch function didn't work for that then I'm sorry I dont know what else to do.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I think this only reloads Python files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn `autoreload` on:

```
tornado.autoreload.start()
tornado.autoreload.watch('myfile')
```

Complete example at https://gist.github.com/renaud/10356841